# Java how to persist a value abstractly?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out the best way to persist a value in Java, which I'm new to using.

I'm used to in Cocoa using NSUserDefaults to persist small amounts of data like ints or strings. The benefit of this is that no matter where the app is launched from or where NSUserDefaults actually writes the data, I know I'll be able to retrieve the same data.

Is there a way to do something like this in Java?

Comment: If your data is simple enough, you could just store it as a JSON. Exactly how complicated of setup you need depends on the exact use-case.

Comment: It's not the format I'm concerned with. How do I know that any Path p is not write-protected? How do I know a FileSystem is even present?

Comment: You will get exceptions if you try to write in a wrong address.

Comment: Use the Java Preferences API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html

Comment: Your question is extremely broad, and difficult to answer in a meaningful way as currently written. Your persistence strategy could be anything from using the file system, or a database, or a properties repository, depending on what your real use-case is here. Consider making your question more specific to what you're trying to do, and you'll likely get a more valuable response here.

Comment: Wait, onnoweb's comment was the answer. Make that an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Java Preferences API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html